# How to fix 401 http response error using Wp cron in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

There was a problem spawning a call to the WP-Cron system on your site. This means WP-Cron events on your site may not work. The problem was: 
Unexpected HTTP response code: 401

I am getting this error while execute the cron job

Comment: Did you look up what HTTP error 401 means?

Comment: Do you have HTTP Basic authentication enabled on your site?

Comment: Did you google `wp cron 401` to find it is probably a permission issue?

Answer (score 9):

Just put this into your .htaccess file

```
# Exclude the WP CRON and other scripts from authentication
<FilesMatch "(wp-cron.php|another-script.php)$">
Satisfy Any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from none
</FilesMatch>
```